# Do the eurosym as indexing

Tags: subscripts

Having trouble doing the indexing for example: A_{rör}, where "rör" should be indexed. This is my code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,swedish]{lips}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{textcomp}

$A_{r\"{o}r}$
```

The compiler gives me an indication of: "\'' command invalid in math mode".
Ive tried to just put the $\''{o}$ and then i get the "ö" in pdf but it isn't indexed. Does anyone know how i fix the problem?

Comment: Welcome! This has nothing to do with `eurosym`. Use `$A_{\textup{r\"or}}$` or simply `$A_{\textup{rör}}$`

Comment: Solved the problem! This may be a dumb question but im kind of new to this, which package in my code gives me the the right to include that?

Comment: That's a feature by `amsmath`.